# What physical forces have stopped Juggernaut?

Tags: marvel, comics, juggernaut

Cain Marko, the Juggernaut, is essentially an unstoppable force if he gets going. He wears a helmet to protect himself from psychic attacks, so many of his stories involve the X-Men attempting to get the helmet off him.

When has Juggernaut been physically stopped in the comics? Methods include blunt force and unexpected walls.

Comment: Spider-man typically webs hit feet and/or pushes him into the floor to stop him

Answer (score 7, accepted):

He's not nearly as unstoppable as he wants you to believe. He has been stopped quite a lot when you look into it.

#### Hulk

Hulk is obviously quite a comparable force. In what I think is their first meeting in *The Incredible Hulk Vol. 1* Issue 172 neither really gets the upper hand on the other with both sending each other flying a few times.

[image: Hulk sends Juggernaut flying to protect some people Juggernaut was picking on]

#### Deadpool and a concrete mixer

In *Despicable Deadpool Vol. 1* Issue 298, Juggernaut tries to collect a bounty on Deadpool's head. Of course the Merc with a Mouth isn't having any of it and runs Juggernaut over with a concrete mixer and then pours the concrete on him.

[image: Deadpool runs Juggernaut over with a concrete mixer; he flies out of the windscreen in the crash and kisses Juggernaut on the noggin] [image: Deadpool covers Juggernaut in concrete before walking away and contemplating the bounty on his head]
<sub>*Click images to enlarge.*</sub>

#### Spider-Man

He gets outsmarted by Spider-Man in *Amazing Spider-Man Vol. 1* Issue 230 and is left in wet cement that he can't escape.

[image: Spider-Man traps Juggernaut in the wet cement as he laments how it won't be able to hold him as he is The Juggernaut]
<sub>*Click image to enlarge.*</sub>

Spider-Man has also used his webs to stop him a few times over the years, such as to trip him up or to tangle him so he can't move.

---

The list goes on but the rule is pretty much the same, either Juggernaut is outsmarted or the two are somewhat evenly matched in power levels. He is stopped more than you would think.

I think it's also worth mentioning, because it's a good film, that whilst I know you want answers from the comics Juggernaut is physically overpowered and pretty evenly matched to Colussus in *Deadpool 2*.

Comment: Was he stopped from his intended trajectory in any of these or just prevented from moving?  Usually he is portrayed as not that hard to hold still but when he gets moving...

Comment: @kaine A bit of both really. And in the fight ones I just picked a panel/page and there's more in the full issue.

Comment: "Spider-Man has also used his webs to stop him a few times over the years, such as to trip him up or to tangle him so he can't move." I *think* I remember a little mini-comic booklet (just a few inches by a few inches) that was distributed as some promotion at some point during the '90s in some supermarket product, where Spider-Man did something like that... Ah, searching indicates it was probably from the Drake's Cakes promotion, "Spider-Man and Wolverine Mini-Comic Set" (1993) #3, "Spider-Man and Wolverine with the Hulk". This particular example is probably not Earth-616 canon, though.

Answer (score 1):

Thor put up a fight in Issue 411:

[image: Juggernaut drives a train car into Thor who destroys it and punches Juggernaut away]